# Qu'est-ce que ça veut dire "C’est qu’on aime en parler nous aut’ souvent"

Tags: sens, pronoms

Le contexte:

> On a vite adopté « week-end » pour son côté facile à prononcer, et sa
>   rapidité par rapport à « la fin de semaine ». C’est qu’on aime **en
>   parler nous aut’ souvent**, du week-end…

La phrase "en parler nous aut’ souvent" me confond.

Comment: Nous aut' est la forme courte de nous autres, expression qui souligne "nous" (et personne d'autre). Que cette expression est lexicalisée se voit aussi dans le mot espagnol "nosotros", où le sens de "autre" ne contribue plus rien.

Comment: @Luke ahh, pourquoi est "nous" pas "parler à nous autres" ou pas "aime nous autres en parler souvent"

Comment: "It is (C'est qu[e]) / we like (on aime) / talking about it (en parler) / us (nous autres) / often (souvent)". It is a fairly regular structure as far as French is concerned. **On** does not usually target a specific person or group by itself, so **nous autres** specifies the value that should be attributed to it in this specific case. *(But also note that **on** is quite commonly used & understood as **nous**, though it is not systematic, and it is also controversial in some circles.)*

Comment: C'est qu'on aime en parler -- That's what we like to talk about, nous autres (=quant à nous), du weekend. Technically both "nous autres" and "du weekend" repeat "on" and "en" respectively, for emphasis.

Comment: I said fairly regular French structure, but it is actually somewhat marginal, common mostly in oral speech. Sorry for the misleading information...

Comment: Je suis familier avec ça, mais pas avec l'ordre dans l'exemple. Je suis davantage familier avec _c'est que nous aut' on aime ça en parler souvent, du week-end_ ou _c'est qu'on aime ça en parler souvent nous aut', du week-end_. L'exemple me confond un peu aussi parce que je perçois comme une double postposition ?

Answer (score 3):

Pour en faire une réponse des commentaires :

« Nous aut' » est une forme abrégée de « nous autres ». Il y a deux choses à dire sur ce sujet.

---

Premièrement ce qui concerne cette expression « nous autres ». Comme tu peux le voir dans ce fil [WordReference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/what-is-the-origin-of-the-french-expression-nous-autres.1104376/), plusieurs langues romanes se servent d'une telle expression, qui a pour origine le « nous exclusif », c'est-à-dire « nous, et non vous à qui nous nous addressons ».

> Nous avons **(tous)** quelque chose en commun.
>
> Par contre, **nous autres** (nous) partageons beacoup, mais vous, vous ne nous ressemblez pas.

Comparez le mot espagnol « nosotros » et d'autres mots en d'autres langues, cités dans ce fil-là.

Mais avec le temps, cette expression « s'aplatit », perd de sa propre nuance de « exclusivité », pour devenir synonyme de « nous ». En effet, en espagnol il ne reste que « nosotros/nosotras » pour exprimer « nous », et ce n'est pas la seule langue qui se comporte ainsi. Mais l'*insistance* sur « nous » comme groupe identifiable, marqué d'une particularité quelconque, demeure.

Selon les autres rédacteurs, l'expression est plus courante au Québec. (Alors @Feelew rapporte que cette expression et la structure emphatique entière qu'on est sur le point de voir sont régulières mais se disent plutôt à l'oral.)

---

OK, donc si on a essentiellement « nous » à ce stade, qu'est-ce que signifie la phrase ?

> C'est qu'on aime en parler, (quant à) nous, souvent, du week-end.

Premièrement, on constate que la phrase a du sens même si réduite à celle-ci :

> C'est qu'on aime en parler, souvent.
>
> <sub>When you consider that we like to talk about it a lot.</sub>

Or ce qui on y ajoute en disant « nous aut' » et « du weekend » sont des précisions emphatiques, qui nous rappellent de quoi il s'agit : « on » veut dire « nous (nous qui ne disons pas *fin de semaine*) », et « en », au cas où l'on a perdu la référence, veut dire « du weekend ».

> C'est qu'on aime en parler nous aut' souvent, du weekend.
>
> <sub>When you consider that us folks like to talk about the *weekend* a lot.</sub>

La'essentiel de cet énoncé est une blague sur la paresse des locuteurs (à un niveau plus soutenu) :

> Quant à nous, nous utilisons le mot « week-end » parce que la rapidité et la facilité dont on peut le prononcer convient bien à nous qui aimons parler du week-end. :)

Ce type de répétition emphatique se produit très souvent là où un mot ou une expression ne convient pas à l'emphase, règle qui s'applique très souvent aux pronoms sujets qui doivent être renforcés.

> Tu dirais ça ? **Moi** je dirais autre chose.
>
> Le parti de mon adversaire ne se soucie pas des besoins des canadiens, mais **nous** on garde vos meilleurs intérêts à cœur.
>
> <sub>Expression préférée de Tom Mulcair (NPD) lors de l'élection fédérale canadienne en 2015.</sub>

Comment: « perd de sa »  ou « perd sa ». Je n'ai pas édité pare ce que je ne suis pas sûr de ce que tu veux dire mais je crois que c'est le genre de typo qu'il faut rectifier. (commentaire à effacer après réponse de l'intéressé)

Comment: Je confirme, l'utilisation de "nous autres" est beaucoup plus courante au   Québec qu'en France.

Comment: Je désire seulement indiquer que je commentais la structure de la phrase et non l'expression *“nous autres”*, bien que cette dernière soit elle aussi le plus souvent reléguée à l'oral. Tom Mulcair n'était-il pas pour le _Nouveau parti démocratique_?

Comment: @Feelew Mon Dieu, à quoi pensais-je quand j'ai écrit cette réponse ?! Mulcair a été rendu à son propre parti et j'espère avoir réproduit précisément ton sens.

Comment: *C'est ce qu'on aime en parler* n'est pas correct. Et *That's what we like to talk about* n'est pas une bonne traduction, ça correspondrait plutot à *C'est de ça qu'on aime parler*. Quant à traduire *C'est qu'on aime en parler* en anglais… c'est plutôt difficile. Je vois pas mieux que *We love to speak about it* dans ce cas, mais si *on* avait été un vrai pronom indéfini ce serait plutôt *Some do like to speak about it*.

Comment: @Stéphane How about « C'est ce dont on aime parler » ? As for the order, it's not surprising to me in regular conversation, where one might decide to emphasize an ambiguous pronoun only after having uttered it. (Some sort of postcedent.) For the translation, a natural literal rendering seems to me to be something along the lines of "That's what *we* like to talk about, anyway, are 'weekends'." But since in context "parler de ___" is introducing the term one uses for a given thing, I chose the English expression "We (like to) say ____."

Comment: Pour *C'est ce dont*, oui, ça marche aussi, c'est juste que (see what I did here) le registre ne colle pas avec l'extrait donné. L'inversion n'est absolument pas possible, les deux existent et ont des sens différents.

Comment: It's hard to describe the effect of a leading *C'est que*. Some kind of empathic emphasis, if it means anything. As in *Oulà ! C'est que c'est compliqué !*.

Comment: @Stéphane Oh, sorry, I just noticed my real error in translation. I understood a *ce* there and even subconsciously put it in brackets. You're right, it's "c'est que"! As the comments on this answer will lead you to conclude, it was not written with my head in the clearest of places. Revising once more!

Comment: Oh, *mind you* is very similar, although it is not as versatile in register.